# Send PC information over TCP

Tags: c#, tcp, windows-services

I am trying to send various bits of PC information such as free HDD space, total RAM etc to a Windows Service over TCP. I have the following code which basically creates a string of information split by a |, ready for processing within the Windows Service TCP server to be put in to a SQL table.

Is it best to do this as I have done or is there a better way?

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program stc = new Program(clientType.TCP);
        stc.tcpClient(serverAddress, Environment.MachineName.ToString() + "|" + FormatBytes(GetTotalFreeSpace("C:\\")).ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("The TCP server is disconnected.");
    }

    public void tcpClient(String serverName, String whatEver)
    {
        try
        {
            //Create an instance of TcpClient.
            TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient(serverName, tcpPort);

            //Create a NetworkStream for this tcpClient instance.
            //This is only required for TCP stream.
            NetworkStream tcpStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

            if (tcpStream.CanWrite)
            {
                Byte[] inputToBeSent = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(whatEver.ToCharArray());

                tcpStream.Write(inputToBeSent, 0, inputToBeSent.Length);

                tcpStream.Flush();
            }

            while (tcpStream.CanRead && !DONE)
            {
                //We need the DONE condition here because there is possibility that
                //the stream is ready to be read while there is nothing to be read.
                if (tcpStream.DataAvailable)
                {
                    Byte[] received = new Byte[512];

                    int nBytesReceived = tcpStream.Read(received, 0, received.Length);

                    String dataReceived = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(received);

                    Console.WriteLine(dataReceived);

                    DONE = true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An Exception has occurred.");
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because TCP is stream-based, it is important to have some indicator in the message to signal the other end when it has read the complete message.  There are two traditional ways of doing this.  First, you could have some special byte pattern at the end of each message.  When the other end reads the data, it knows that it has read a full message when that special byte pattern is seen.  Using this mechanism requires a byte pattern that is not likely to be included in the actual message.  The other way is to include the length of the data at the beginning of the message.  This is the way I do it.  All my TCP messages include a short header structured like this:

```
class MsgHeader
{
    short syncPattern;  // e.g., 0xFDFD
    short msgType;      // useful if you have different messages
    int   msgLength;    // length of the message minus header
}
```

When the other side starts receiving data, it reads the first 8 bytes, verifies the sync pattern (for the sake of sanity), and then uses the message length to read the actual message.  Once the message has been read, it processes the message based on the message type.

---

I'd suggest creating a class that gathers the system information you're interested in and is capable of encoding/decoding it, something like:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

class SystemInfo
{
    private string machineName;
    private int freeSpace;
    private int processorCount;

    // Private so no one can create it directly.
    private SystemInfo()
    {
    }

    // This is a static method now.  Call SystemInfo.Encode() to use it.
    public static byte[] Encode()
    {
        // Convert the machine name to an ASCII-based byte array.
        var machineNameAsByteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Environment.MachineName);

        // *THIS IS IMPORTANT*  The easiest way to encode a string value so that it
        // can be easily decoded is to prepend the length of the string.  Otherwise,
        // you're left guessing on the decode side about how long the string is.

        // Calculate the message length.  This does *NOT* include the size of
        // the message length itself.
        // NOTE:  As new fields are added to the message, account for their
        //        respective size here and encode them below.
        var messageLength = sizeof(int)                   + // length of machine name string
                            machineNameAsByteArray.Length + // the machine name value
                            sizeof(int)                   + // free space
                            sizeof(int);                    // processor count

        // Calculate the required size of the byte array.  This *DOES* include
        // the size of the message length.
        var byteArraySize = messageLength + // message itself
                            sizeof(int);    // 4-byte message length field

        // Allocate the byte array.
        var bytes = new byte[byteArraySize];

        // The offset is used to keep track of where the next field should be
        // placed in the byte array.
        var offset = 0;

        // Encode the message length (a very simple header).
        Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(messageLength), 0, bytes, offset, sizeof(int));

        // Increment offset by the number of bytes added to the byte array.
        // Note that the increment is equal to the value of the last parameter
        // in the preceding BlockCopy call.
        offset += sizeof(int);

        // Encode the length of machine name to make it easier to decode.
        Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(machineNameAsByteArray.Length), 0, bytes, offset, sizeof(int));

        // Increment the offset by the number of bytes added.
        offset += sizeof(int);

        // Encode the machine name as an ASCII-based byte array.
        Buffer.BlockCopy(machineNameAsByteArray, 0, bytes, offset, machineNameAsByteArray.Length);

        // Increment the offset.  See the pattern?
        offset += machineNameAsByteArray.Length;

        // Encode the free space.
        Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(GetTotalFreeSpace("C:\\")), 0, bytes, offset, sizeof(int));

        // Increment the offset.
        offset += sizeof(int);

        // Encode the processor count.
        Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(Environment.ProcessorCount), 0, bytes, offset, sizeof(int));

        // No reason to do this, but it completes the pattern.
        offset += sizeof(int).

        return bytes;
    }

    // Static method.  Call is as SystemInfo.Decode(myReceivedByteArray);
    public static SystemInfo Decode(byte[] message)
    {
        // When decoding, the presumption is that your socket code read the first
        // four bytes from the socket to determine the length of the message.  It
        // then allocated a byte array of that size and read the message into that
        // byte array.  So the byte array passed into this function does *NOT* have
        // the 4-byte message length field at the front of it.  It makes no sense
        // in this class anyway.

        // Create the SystemInfo object to be populated and returned.
        var si = new SystemInfo();

        // Use the offset to navigate through the byte array.
        var offset = 0;

        // Extract the length of the machine name string since that is the first
        // field encoded in the message.
        var machineNameLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(message, offset);

        // Increment the offset.
        offset += sizeof(int);

        // Extract the machine name now that we know its length.
        si.machineName = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(message, offset, machineNameLength);

        // Increment the offset.
        offset += machineNameLength;

        // Extract the free space.
        si.freeSpace = BitConverter.ToInt32(message, offset);

        // Increment the offset.
        offset += sizeof(int);

        // Extract the processor count.
        si.processorCount = BitConverter.ToInt32(message, offset);

        // No reason to do this, but it completes the pattern.
        offset += sizeof(int);

        return si;
    }
}
```

To encode the data, call the `Encode` method like this:

```
byte[] msg = SystemInfo.Encode();
```

To decode the data once it's been read from the socket, call the `Decode` method like this:

```
SystemInfo si = SystemInfo.Decode(msg);
```

As to your actual code, I'm not sure why you're reading from the socket after writing to it unless you're expecting a return value.

A few things to consider.  Hope this helps.

#### EDIT

First of all, use the `MsgHeader` if you feel you need it.  The example above simply uses the message length as the header, i.e., it does not include a sync pattern or a message type.  Whether you need to use this additional information is up to you.

For every new field you add to the `SystemInfo` class, the overall size of the message will increased, obviously.  Thus, the `messageLength` value needs to be adjusted accordingly.  For example, if you add an `int` to include the number of processors, `messageLength` will increase by `sizeof(int)`.  Then, to add it to the byte array, simply use the same [`System.Buffer.BlockCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) call.  I've adjusted the example to show this with a little more detail, including making the method static.

Comment: Thanks for this, although I am a bit confused as to the final structure of the Encoded bytes. How do I add more than the machine name and free space to the byte array? Is it possible for you to alter the code to show a few more variables in the encoded message? Also, do I still need to use the MsgHeader class? Cheers

Comment: @MattBaughan, I added a processor count field to the example, plus the decode logic.  HTH.